# Chrome shares sites as "text/plain"

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that can accept a text file.

```
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".ImportKeywords"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/prefTitleImportKeywords"
        android:targetActivity=".GalleryActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

If a user selects to share a website it offers my app as an option which is undesirable.  Here's an example intent from Chrome:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x13400001 cmp=com.anthonymandra.rawdroidpro/com.anthonymandra.rawdroid.ImportKeywords clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/BlockedFile_286732125806812} (has extras) }
```

It's type is "text/plain".

Any idea how I can avoid these intents while still accepting "text/plain"?